# Why does std::pair return such a random 'second' value?

Tags: c++, std-pair

The issue is that I want to return a pair containing my key and value {8, 8} for example. Instead I get a rather random pair back {8, 19259321} for example, and I'm not sure why, but I'm guessing I'm trying to do something with references that is causing UB. Below is a reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Key, typename Value>
class Tree {
public:
    class Node {
    public:
        Key key;
        Value value;

        Node(Key k, Value v)
        {
            key = k;
            value = v;
        }
    };

    class iterator {
        using pointer_type = Node*;
        using reference = std::pair<const Key, Value>&;

        pointer_type t_Ptr;
    public:
        iterator(pointer_type ptr) : t_Ptr(ptr) {}

        // For the sake of the minimal reproduciable problem, this is the only operator.
        reference operator*() const
        {
            return (std::pair<const Key, Value>&)(t_Ptr->key, t_Ptr->value);
        }
    };
private:
    size_t treeSize;
    Node* root;
};

int main()
{
    Tree<int, int>::Node* testNode = new Tree<int, int>::Node(8, 8);

    Tree<int, int>::iterator it = Tree<int, int>::iterator(testNode);
    std::pair<int, int> myPair = *it;
    std::cout << myPair.first << ", " << myPair.second << std::endl;
}
```

The issue is my dereference operator in the iterator.

I should also mention, that the reason my return statement below looks the way it does, is because it was the only solution I found, where I didn't get any errors. In all the other ways I tried returning a pair, it would give me an error similar to

> couldn't convert from the list initializer to pair<const Key, Value>&

```
return (std::pair<const Key, Value>&)(t_Ptr->key, t_Ptr->value);
```

Comment: You are returning the address of a temporary. You need to return a reference to the Node. Why not make the Node a std::pair?

Comment: The code should not compile. You are shadowing a template parameter which is not allowed.

Comment: @user17732522 [Indeed it doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/ahdsd43cW) on GCC trunk.

Comment: By the way, if your original question didn't have an MRE, you're supposed to edit the original question to include the necessary information/code, instead of posting a new question.

Comment: Even if I try to fix the shadowing issue, I get warnings that are probably significant: https://godbolt.org/z/ondWxMKPh

Comment: Repost of [Why does std::pair return such a random 'second' value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72217559/why-does-stdpair-return-such-a-random-second-value)

Comment: @user17732522 It fails to compile in gcc and clang but compiles in msvc. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9fM9dEbdn)

Comment: `using reference = std::pair<const Key&, Value&>;`

Comment: @AnoopRana Hm, I haven't looked it up, but I think GCC and Clang are correct here. But I guess it is not that important to the question.

Comment: I editted my old question, but it was closed and could not be answered by anyone anymore, hence I figured I had to repost it. The code compiles fine for me in Visual Studio, but I guess other compilers don't like my code?

Comment: @DrewDormann The duplicate is relevant, but does not immediately apply to the code. The function is actually returning a mis-cast reference to `t_Ptr->value`, not a reference to a temporary.

Comment: @cppnoob There is a process for reopening questions after they have been edited to remove the reason for the closure. Unfortunately that process can take a while since the number of viewers of the question is usually smaller than for new questions.

Comment: @user17732522 oh my bad, I wasn't aware of that, it's not often I post on here. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. I fixed the shadowing issue, that was silly of me in the first place. Then I changed the node class from having two variables Key and Value, to having one std::pair containing those two values. Then I could instead return that pair, instead of trying to create and return a temporary one, that'd cause UB. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Reopened.  The duplicate-closure was based on code that has since been changed.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a problem solver helper. Do not edit the question to have fixed code. Write an answer instead with the fixed code.

Comment: @cppnoob to complement j6t's comment of "*Do not edit the question to have fixed code. Write an answer instead with the fixed code*", see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I apologise many times. I changed it back to the original question, only with the minimal reproducible example being compilable, aswell as posting my solution as an answer. I will mark it as the solution in 2 days, when it allows me to. Hopefully everything is alright now. I'll keep it all in mind for next time I post on here, lol.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue. There was a shadowing issue firstly, which I believe I fixed. And instead of having two variables in my class node 'Key' and 'Value', I made one std::pair variable instead, containig both key and value. Then I could return that pair, instead of trying to create and return a new temporary pair, that would cause UB. Fixed code below.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Key, typename Value>
class Tree {
public:
    // I removed the template here, as it was unnecessary.
    class Node {
    public:
        // Changed the two variables to a pair.
        std::pair<const Key, Value> pair;
        // Therefore constructor had to be changed too
        Node(Key k, Value v) : pair(k, v) {}
    };

    class iterator {
        using pointer_type = Node*;
        using reference = std::pair<const Key, Value>&;

        pointer_type t_Ptr;
    public:
        iterator(pointer_type ptr) : t_Ptr(ptr) {}

        // For the sake of the minimal reproduciable problem, this is the only operator.
        reference operator*()
        {
            // I could now just return the variable 'pair'
            return t_Ptr->pair;
        }
    };
private:
    size_t treeSize;
    Node* root;
};

int main()
{
    Tree<int, int>::Node* testNode = new Tree<int, int>::Node(8, 8);

    Tree<int, int>::iterator it = Tree<int, int>::iterator(testNode);
    std::pair<int, int> myPair = *it;
    std::cout << myPair.first << ", " << myPair.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```